# On which part of the DNA will the new DNA nucleotide connect?

Tags: dna

My question is:

> Where will the new DNA nucleotide connect on the (part of the) DNA shown on the picture? Will it connect to the phosphate group?

What does the 5' --> 3' mean?

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers come from the numbering of the carbon atom of the ribose in the backbone of the DNA. The ribose is numbered as shown in the figure below:

[image]

In the nucleotides the phosphate groups are attached to the 5' carbon atom and new nucleotide will be added at the 3' carbon atom. See the image below:

[image]

First you have a OH-group at the 3' position which is then "replaced" by the new nucleotide.